# The underscore of an ivar got lost when referencing to it in a objective c subclass?

Tags: objective-c

Here is the code:

**Rectangle.h**

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>

@interface Rectangle : NSObject

@property int width;
@property int height;

- (int)area;
- (int)perimeter;
- (void)setWidth:(int)w andHeight:(int)h;

@end
```

**Rectangle.m**

```
#import "Rectangle.h"

@implementation Rectangle

- (int)area
{
    return _width * _height;
}

- (int)perimeter
{
    return (_width + _height) * 2;
}
- (void)setWidth:(int)w andHeight:(int)h
{
    _width = w;
    _height = h;
}

@end
```

**Square.h**

```
#import "Rectangle.h"

@interface Square : Rectangle

- (void)setSide:(int)a;
- (int)side;

@end
```

**Square.m**

```
#import "Square.h"

@implementation Square

- (void)setSide:(int)s
{
    [self setWidth:s andHeight:s];
}

- (int)side
{
    return self._width;
}

@end
```

The problem is happening in the `- (int)side` method of `Square.m`. It doesn't work unless I change `self._width` to `self.width`. Why is this though? When I made the property in `Rectangle.h`, I did not synthesize it in `Rectangle.m`, so the `ivar` `_width` was automatically created. Since the property was declared in `.h`, isn't the `ivar` public? Or is it not public and what I am actually seeing is the hidden getter of the property width? So is it really doing:

```
- (int)side
{
    return [self width];
}
```

The dot notation has me confused as to if it is referring to the `ivar`, or the getter method of the property itself. Can someone clarify that there is not any width `ivar`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> The dot notation has me confused as to if it is referring to the ivar,
>   or the getter method of the property itself. Can someone clarify that
>   there is not any width ivar?

The dot notation refers to the property accessor, `width` in this case. That is,

```
int foo = someSquare.width;
```

is exactly the same as:

```
int foo = [someSquare width];
```

So, trying to use dot notation with a leading underscore, `self._width`, doesn't make sense because there is no property named `_width`. There is an instance variable named `_width`, but you don't access it using dot notation.

> Since the property was declared in .h, isn't the ivar public?

Yes, the ivar is publicly accessible, and you can get to it using pointer notation:

```
int foo = self->_width;
```

but don't do that. Use the property accessor instead.

Comment: Thanks for clarifying. I guess I thought that dot notation could be used to access ivars.

Comment: Objective-C's dot notation looks like the dot notation used to access fields in a struct, so it's an understandable mistake.

Comment: Since the ivar isn't in the header, it shouldn't be available to the subclass (in a different file). There is no public information about how the methods are backed.

Comment: @BrianNickel Good point -- I guess I was thinking of objects of the same class. At any rate, the takeaway should be that you should use property accessors in almost all cases.